# Angular 2 SPA loading screen not showing Visual Studio 2017

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I am unable to get a loading screen to show on my Angular 2 SPA Template with VS 2017 Community.

I have the following in my index.cshtml.

```
<app asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server">
    <h1>APP IS LOADING</h1>
    <div class="loader"></div>
</app>
```

The class I have for the .loader (which is in my app.component.css file)

```
.loader {
    border: 16px solid #f3f3f3; /* Light grey */
    border-top: 16px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

My app.component.html is;

```
<nav-menu></nav-menu>
<hero></hero>
<div class='container-fluid'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-sm-12 body-content'>
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </div>   
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

Where my app.component.ts is;

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

However, when I load the page the page is loading and text images seem to be loading on the fly (I have tested this after a publish to my server too, and added a large background image to test, which shows as a grey box til the image slowly loads in).

Am I missing something here?

Comment: I guess app component uses encapsulation mode `Emulated`. In this case you have to use ::ng-deep > .loader

Comment: I see what your saying, but that doesnt explain why the h1 isnt at least appearing? i.e. its showing doesnt seem to be showing the html inside the node until all the angular views are loaded?

Comment: If your AppComponent template did not contain a <ng-content> tag, h1 and div did not have a place where there can be rendered. They will be ignored.

Comment: Hmm, I updated the question to include my app.component file too so you can see my router-outlet, does this help at all?

Answer (score 0):

Your `h1` and `div` tags will not be shown because at runtime angular puts the components template under your `app` tag.

index.html  at runtime when angular loaded

```
<app>
  <nav-menu></nav-menu>
  <hero></hero>
  <div class='container-fluid'>
      <div class='row'>
          <div class='col-sm-12 body-content'>
              <router-outlet></router-outlet>
          </div>
      </div>   
  </div>
</app>
```

Include the tags for the loader into your template and there they will be shown.

app.component.html

```
<nav-menu></nav-menu>
<hero></hero>

<div asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server">
    <h1>APP IS LOADING</h1>
    <div class="loader"></div>
</div>

<div class='container-fluid'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-sm-12 body-content'>
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </div>   
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

EDIT:
If that is a problem you can show the loader stuff outside of app.

index.cshtml

```
<div asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server">
    <h1>APP IS LOADING</h1>
    <div class="loader"></div>
</div>
<app></app>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you just clarify for me please (new to angular 2). As far as I was aware the the .netcore routing sends the request to the index.csthml, which then loads the angular app from the bundled main-server.js and then replaces that <div> with the app. so basically I'm unsure how I can pull the asp-prerender-module (which is a server side tag as well isnt it?) into the app.component.html file?

Comment: I do not now much about this asp-prerender-module. But if its only a spinner or something than put it directly in the index file. See edit.